# How to download published app from apple store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app published on the apple store and I want to download the files I uploaded. I've been searching but struggling to find instructions. Is it possible to download app files, if so, how?

Comment: Just download it like how you download any other application?

Comment: The whole app. My computer crashed and I to download all the files.

Comment: I was hopping. Newbie learning from YouTube and forums. I guess I’ll have to recreate everything.

Comment: If you don’t have the source files then you will need to recreate them. Use git and a service like github or bitbucket for version control. Use time machine for backup

Comment: Thank you everyone. Good thing it was a simple app. Thank you for pointing me to time machine.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not store your source code. You upload a signed-IPA to App Store Connect, which then gets re-signed by Apple and once approved, people will download this on the App Store. There is no way for you to download the uploaded developer-signed IPA.

To store you source code, I recommend using `GIT` with (free) services like [GitHub](https://github.com), [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.com) or [GitLab](https://gitlab.com). This will allow you to store your source code securely and have a version history of changes.

The only option locally to recover your source code would be using `Time Machine` or similar for backups of your Mac.